# Can't get the view file

Tags: jsp, tomcat, struts, netbeans-7

I'm new in struts framework. When I work on a project I am facing a problem. My jsp view page never return any output. I already check all the variable and I think my coding hasn't any variable problem.I set a log file. Here is the log file text. I am working on struts version 1.3.10 and Apache Tomcat 7.0.22. I am using NetBeans IDE 7.1

here is the log file text

```
   DEBUG Get module name for path /accountList.do
   DEBUG Module name found: default
   DEBUG Processing a 'GET' for path '/accountList'
   DEBUG  Looking for ActionForm bean instance in scope 'request' under attribute key 'AccountForm'
   DEBUG  Creating new ActionForm instance of type 'accountManagement.AccountForm'
   DEBUG  --> accountManagement.AccountForm@1c89b2b
   DEBUG  Storing ActionForm bean instance in scope 'request' under attribute key 'AccountForm'
   DEBUG  Populating bean properties from this request
   DEBUG BeanUtils.populate(accountManagement.AccountForm@1c89b2b, {})
   DEBUG  Validating input form properties
   DEBUG   No errors detected, accepting input
   DEBUG  Looking for Action instance for class accountManagement.AccountAction
   DEBUG   Creating new Action instance
   DEBUG Connection established to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vos3000db...
   DEBUG Account Management Detail SQL:Select * from e_customer;
   DEBUG Account Management Detail Value:[accountManagement.AccountDTO@1bf9583, ...]
   DEBUG Account Management List Size:41
   DEBUG Account Management List Size:2
   DEBUG Account Management:RECORD_PER_PAGE_FOR_ACCOUNT:25
   DEBUG processForwardConfig(/accountManagement/view.jsp)
   DEBUG   '/accountManagement/view.jsp' - processed as uri
   DEBUG processForwardConfig(ForwardConfig[name=success,path=/accountManagement/view.jsp,redirect=false,module=null,extends=null,catalog=null,command=null])
   DEBUG Initializing, 
                                config='org.apache.struts.util.LocalStrings', returnNull=true
   INFO  Operating in Default mode [null]
   DEBUG Initializing,  
                         config='org.apache.struts.taglib.html.LocalStrings', returnNull=true
   INFO  Operating in Default mode [null]
   DEBUG Initializing, 
                         config='org.apache.struts.taglib.html.LocalStrings', returnNull=true
   INFO  Operating in Default mode [null]
   DEBUG getMessage(en_US,lookup.bean.any)
   DEBUG loadLocale(en_US)
   DEBUG   Loading resource 'org/apache/strus/taglib   
                                                 /LocalStrings_en_US.properties'
   WARN    Resource org/apache/struts/taglib/LocalStrings_en_US.properties Not Found.
   DEBUG loadLocale(en)
   DEBUG   Loading resource 'org/apache/struts/taglib/LocalStrings_en.properties'
   WARN    Resource org/apache/struts/taglib/LocalStrings_en.properties Not Found.
   DEBUG loadLocale()
   DEBUG   Loading resource 'org/apache/struts/taglib/LocalStrings.properties'
   DEBUG   Loading resource completed
   DEBUG   Saving message key '.message.bundle
```

Comment: This is not enough to help; we know nothing of your configuration, what action you're requesting (i.e., what are you using as your request URL), nothing.

Comment: Since you say jsp never return any output, i suggest you to put a plain <html> with "Hello World" message. But my guess is there will be mapping issue.